# Is it possible to obtain explicit symbolic solutions to such linear ordinary differential equations?

Tags: differential-equations

The ordinary differential equations to solve have symbolic parameters $k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4,k_5,k_6 \in \mathbb{R}$.
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
{y_1}'(t)=-{k_1} {y_1}(t)-{k_2} {y_1}(t),\\
{y_2}'(t)={k_2} {y_1}(t)-{k_3} {y_2}(t),\\
{y_3}'(t)={k_1}   {y_1}(t)+{k_3} {y_2}(t)-{k_4} {y_3}(t),\\
{y_4}'(t)={k_4} {y_3}(t)-{k_5} {y_2}(t) {y_4}(t)+{k_6} {y_5}(t),\\
{y_5}'(t)={k_5} {y_2}(t) {y_4}(t)-{k_6} {y_5}(t)\\
\end{array}
\right.$$

The ODE system itself seems simple when all $k_i$ are numerical numbers. 
How to solve it symbolically ? Is it possible to obtain explicit solutions?

Update:

Expressions in MMA:(DSolve does not work for such nonlinear ODE system)

```
  DSolve[{D[y1[t], t] == -k1*y1[t] - k2*y1[t],
  D[y2[t], t] == k2*y1[t] - k3*y2[t],
  D[y3[t], t] == k1*y1[t] + k3*y2[t] - k4*y3[t],
  D[y4[t], t] == k4*y3[t] - k5*y2[t]*y4[t] + k6*y5[t],
  D[y5[t], t] == k5*y2[t]*y4[t] - k6*y5[t]}, {y1[t], y2[t], y3[t], 
  y4[t], y5[t]}, t]
```

Comment: Did you already try `DSolve`? It would be good if you could provide the equations in *Mathematica* input form. It would let potential answerers try their solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This ODE system can't be solved symbolically with the given information.
First let's define the differential equations:

```
dg1 = y1'[t] == -k1 y1[t] - k2 y1[t]
dg2 = y2'[t] == k2 y1[t] - k3 y2[t]
dg3 = y3'[t] == k1 y1[t] + k3 y2[t] - k4 y3[t]
dg4 = y4'[t] == k4 y3[t] - k5 y2[t] y4[t] + k6 y5[t]
dg5 = y5'[t] == k5 y2[t] y4[t] - k6 y5[t]
```

Now the first three differential equations can be solved, because these are independent of the last two.

```
pSol = DSolve[{dg1, dg2, dg3}, {y1[t], y2[t], y3[t]}, t]
```

> ```
> {{y1[t] -> E^((-k1 - k2) t) C[1], 
>   y2[t] -> (E^(-k3 t) (-1 + E^((-k1 - k2) t + k3 t)) k2 C[1])/(-k1 - k2 + k3) + E^(-k3 t) C[2], 
>   y3[t] -> (E^(-k3 t - k4 t) (E^(k3 t) k1^2 k3 - 
>      E^((-k1 - k2) t + k3 t + k4 t) k1^2 k3 + 
>      2 E^(k3 t) k1 k2 k3 - E^(k4 t) k1 k2 k3 - 
>      E^((-k1 - k2) t + k3 t + k4 t) k1 k2 k3 + E^(k3 t) k2^2 k3 - 
>      E^(k4 t) k2^2 k3 - E^(k3 t) k1 k3^2 + 
>      E^((-k1 - k2) t + k3 t + k4 t) k1 k3^2 - E^(k3 t) k2 k3^2 + 
>      E^((-k1 - k2) t + k3 t + k4 t) k2 k3^2 - E^(k3 t) k1^2 k4 + 
>      E^((-k1 - k2) t + k3 t + k4 t) k1^2 k4 - E^(k3 t) k1 k2 k4 + 
>      E^((-k1 - k2) t + k3 t + k4 t) k1 k2 k4 + E^(k3 t) k1 k3 k4 -
>       E^((-k1 - k2) t + k3 t + k4 t) k1 k3 k4 + 
>      E^(k4 t) k2 k3 k4 - 
>      E^((-k1 - k2) t + k3 t + k4 t) k2 k3 k4) C[1])/((k1 + k2 - k3) (k1 + k2 - k4) (k3 - k4)) - 
>      (E^(-k3 t - k4 t) (-E^(k3 t) + E^(k4 t)) k3 C[2])/(k3 - k4) + 
>      E^(-k4 t) C[3]
> }}
> ```

From the last differential equation we get

```
Solve[dg5, y5[t]]
```

> ```
> {{y5[t] -> (k5 y2[t] y4[t] - y5'[t])/k6}}
> ```

This (or even easier to see `k6 y5[t]`) can be inserted into the fourth differential equation

```
dg4 /. (First@%)
```

> ```
> y4'[t] == k4 y3[t] - y5'[t]
> ```

(Note that there is no `y5[t]` left.)
Inserting also `pSol` and applying `Simplify` provides the remaining equation

```
% /. (First@pSol) // Simplify
```

> ```
> (E^(-(k3 + k4) t) k4 (E^((-k1 - k2 + k3 + k4) t) (k1 + k2) (k1 - k3) (k3 - k4) C[1] - 
>   E^(k4 t) k3 (-k1 - k2 + k4) ((k1 - k3) C[2] + k2 (C[1] + C[2])) - 
>   E^(k3 t) (k1 + k2 - k3) (k4 (k4 C[3] - k3 (C[2] + C[3])) + 
>   k2 (-k4 C[3] + k3 (C[1] + C[2] + C[3])) + 
>   k1 (-k4 (C[1] + C[3]) + k3 (C[1] + C[2] + C[3])))))/((k1 + k2 - k3) (k1 + k2 - k4) (k3 - k4)) + 
>   y4'[t] + y5'[t] == 0
> ```

If one tries to solve this equation using

```
DSolve[%, {y4[t], y5[t]}, {t}]
```

the following message is received

> DSolve::underdet: There are more dependent variables than equations, so the system is underdetermined. >>

The remaining equation can be solved for `y4[t]`, though.

```
DSolve[%%, {y4[t]}, {t}]
```

> ```
> {{y4[t] -> 
>    C[4] + (E^(-(k1 + k2) t) (k1 - k3) (k3 - k4) k4 C[1] + 
>    E^(-(k3 + k4) t) (-E^(k4 t) k4 (-k1 - k2 + k4) ((k1 - k3) C[2] + k2 (C[1] + C[2])) - 
>    E^(k3 t) (k1 + k2 - k3) (k4 (k4 C[3] - k3 (C[2] + C[3])) + 
>    k2 (-k4 C[3] + k3 (C[1] + C[2] + C[3])) + 
>    k1 (-k4 (C[1] + C[3]) + 
>    k3 (C[1] + C[2] + C[3])))) - (k1 + k2 - k3) (k1 + k2 - k4) (k3 - k4) y5[t])/((k1 + k2 - k3) (k1 + k2 - k4) (k3 - k4))
>  }}
> ```

The ODE system can also be solved, e.g. if `y5'[t]` is a constant.

---

Additional note:
With the solutions of the first three equations (`pSol`), the remaining equations can be rewritten as

```
y4'[t] == k6 y5[t] - a[t] y4[t] + b[t]
y5'[t] == a[t] y4[t] - k6 y5[t]
```

Therefore the remaining problem is to solve this non-homogeneous first-order linear differential equation with variable coefficients.

Comment: I also tried the same methods. I originally was trying to fit $k_i$s via measured data as below `{{30.0, 9.1300, 0.0931, 0.0899, 0.1000, 0.0000},
{60.0, 8.9261, 0.1270, 0.1229, 0.2272, 0.0049},
{90.0, 8.6006, 0.1509, 0.1392, 0.4917, 0.0153},
{120.0, 8.2823, 0.1537, 0.1491, 0.7783, 0.0249},
{150.0, 7.9652, 0.1537, 0.1567, 1.0716, 0.0329},
{180.0, 7.8637, 0.1536, 0.1603, 1.1659, 0.0348},
{210.0, 7.8120, 0.1530, 0.1532, 1.2140, 0.0404},
{240.0, 7.7652, 0.1403, 0.1417, 1.2795, 0.0432}}`, columns represents $t$ and $y_i$ respectively

Comment: Is it to solve the prolbem http://mathoverflow.net/questions/178192/how-to-fit-the-parameters-of-differential-equations-with-known-data via MMA?

Comment: @LCFactorization at least you can use `pSol` to fit `k1`, `k2`, `k3`, and `k4`.

Comment: so it is still impossible to obtain them all?

Comment: @LCFactorization It isn't impossible. The remaining problem (see my additional note) generally has a formal solution, but it is in general not a simple function that would be suitable for a fitting procedure. So far I didn't encounter this class of equations in my experimental systems and therefore can't give you any further advice on how to tackle it.